# Natural extension of the line element for the Lagrangian to fields over 3+1 spacetime?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, field-theory

We are all familiar with the standard construction of the Lagrangian of a free relativistic particle:

Start with the definition

$$
S=\int_{\Delta t}ds. \tag{1}
$$

Then use the definition of the line element $ds=\sqrt{g_{\mu\nu}dX^\mu dX^\nu}$

$$
S=\int_{\Delta t} \sqrt{g_{\mu\nu} dX^\mu dX^\nu}\tag{2}
$$

Then parametrize $dX^\mu dX^\nu$ with respect to, say, $\lambda$:

$$
S=\int_{\Delta t}\sqrt{g_{\mu\nu} \tfrac{\partial X^\mu}{\partial \lambda} \tfrac{\partial X^\nu}{\partial \lambda}}d\lambda\tag{3}
$$

In the case of special relativity the action becomes:

$$
S=\int_{\Delta t} \sqrt{\left(\tfrac{\partial X^0}{\partial \lambda}\right)^2-\left(\tfrac{\partial X^2}{\partial \lambda}\right)^2-\left(\tfrac{\partial X^2}{\partial \lambda}\right)^2-\left(\tfrac{\partial X^3}{\partial \lambda}\right)^2} d\lambda \tag{4}
$$

---

Now, if one takes the Scalar free field, the action is:

$$
S=\int_{\Delta t}\int_{\Delta z}\int_{\Delta y}\int_{\Delta x} \frac{1}{2} \eta_{\mu\nu} \partial^\mu \phi \partial^\nu \phi dxdydzdt \tag{5}
$$

Using the relation $\frac{1}{2}L^2\to L$, we can write the above as:

$$
S=\int_{\Delta t}\int_{\Delta z}\int_{\Delta y}\int_{\Delta x}  \sqrt{\eta_{\mu\nu} \partial^\mu \phi \partial^\nu \phi} dxdydzdt \tag{6}
$$

Which becomes

$$
S=\int_{\Delta t}\int_{\Delta z}\int_{\Delta y}\int_{\Delta x}  \sqrt{\left( \tfrac{\partial \phi}{\partial t}\right)^2 - \left( \tfrac{\partial \phi}{\partial x} \right)^2- \left( \tfrac{\partial \phi}{\partial y} \right)^2- \left( \tfrac{\partial \phi}{\partial z} \right)^2} dxdydzdt \tag{7}
$$

I find (4) to be so similar to (7) that I am wondering if there is a procedure similar to how we went from (1) to (4), but could bring a Lagrangian density from one to eventually four integration variable such that (7) is recovered.

For instance, can we generalize the procedure expressed for the one-dimensional case in [(1) to (4)], but to two dimensions:

$$
S=\int_{\Delta t} ds_1 \wedge ds_2\tag{8}
$$

such that $ds_1$ and $ds_2$ are two linearly independent line elements, then extend it to 4 dimensions:

$$
S=\int_{\Delta t} ds_1 \wedge ds_2 \wedge ds_3 \wedge ds_4. \tag{9}
$$

Answer (score 2):

It seems relevant to mention the [Nambu-Goto action for $p$-branes](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Nambu-Goto+action)

$$S_{NG}[\phi]~=~\int_{\Sigma}{\rm dvol} (\phi^{\ast}(g)),\tag{A}$$
which is the volume of the [pullback](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pullback) $\phi^{\ast}(g)$ of the target space metric to the $p$-brane world volume $\Sigma$ of dimension $p+1$. In local coordinates, the Lagrangian density is the square root of the determinant of the induced metric components. Here $$\underbrace{\Sigma}_{p\text{-brane world volume}}\quad\stackrel{\phi}{\longrightarrow}\quad \underbrace{(M,g)}_{\text{target space}}.\tag{B}$$

OP's eqs. (1)-(4) are the action (A) for the case $p=0$. The world volume $\Sigma$ is a 3+1D spacetime in the case $p=3$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I am aware of the Namby-Goto action for p-branes integrated into a higher dimensional spacetime (D>p). What I am looking for is a general action where one takes the usual relativistic lagrangian in 1D (equations (1) to (4) in my question) and increase the number of dependant variables on the $X$ such that they must be parametrized via 4 variables. Thus one starts with $X[\lambda]$ and converts them to fields $X[x,y,z,t]$. The integral becomes a field integral, but how does the square root term 'naturally' change for as the number of dependants variables is increased?